# Url rewrite error

Tags: magento2, database, rest-api, url-rewrite

Can anyone please help me on this? i'm calling all my product name and sku from an external api and save to database but unfortunately when i run cron i'm getting following error on log and the api stopped executing. I will be very happy for any assistance.

```
URL key for specified store already exists. at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage/DbStorage.php:310, Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\AlreadyExistsException(code: 0): URL key for specified store already exists. at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage/DbStorage.php:344, Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\DuplicateException(code: 1062): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '512gb-pcie-nvme-value-ssd.html-1' for key 'url_rewrite.URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT  INTO `url_rewrite` (`redirect_type`,`is_autogenerated`,`metadata`,`description`,`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`request_path`,`target_path`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:599, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '512gb-pcie-nvme-value-ssd.html-1' for key 'url_rewrite.URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT  INTO `url_rewrite` (`redirect_type`,`is_autogenerated`,`metadata`,`description`,`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`request_path`,`target_path`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '512gb-pcie-nvme-value-ssd.html-1' for key 'url_rewrite.URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID' at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

[2022-09-27 10:39:55] main.INFO: Cron Job tech_system_cron_techintegration is run [] []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into your admin and go to Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites

Search in 'Request Path' for the key you're trying to add.

Delete all instances.

Try again.

Comment: thanks a lot. works perfectly

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: this is not a permanent solution because always you are not able to remove urls.
is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Only through the Database directly. I don't know the query you'd need to use, but I would bet it's somewhere on the internet if you look hard enough

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this issue with saving categories in magento backend after a migration. What i usually do for fixing a few cases is searching for the "product-url-key" in Catalog->inventory->product remember not to add .html in the search, and fix case by case.

In your case you should search for **"512gb-pcie-nvme-value-ssd"**

Then if you find more that one case, you need to edit the product and modify the URL. remember **NOT** to click to "Create Permanent Redirect for old URL"

If you just went to a migration i would recomend then find in the databases all url keys that are not unique and fix them. Please rememeber to check the scope of your store as this impact on the url key. This can be done by exporting all the url keys to excel and using duplicate values function for example.

Also, it helped for my from a migration, changing the visibility of simple products that have a configurable to "not visible individualy" as this removes the key and the conflic. In magento 1 usually the simple products were generated with the same key as the configurable. Also the scope is again important for this.